# How to get $nid inside hook_menu_alter function

Tags: routes

I'm trying to show or hide a menu tab based on whether my node meets a certain condition. In my hook_menu_alter I can't seem to get the $nid even though I was under the impression that the menu_alter fired after node load...

I've been googling for a day now and trying different solutions, but just can't seem to access the $nid.

When I print arg(0) or $_GET['q'] I get the result "admin_menu/flush-cache" instead of "node/62" even though I'm on a node page... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menus are cached; unless you have something funky going on, loading a node won't rebuild that cache (it would be frightfully expensive to do so).

You need to make 'live' decisions in a callback, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['foo']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_access_callback';
}

function MYMODULE_access_callback() {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node && $node->bar) {
    return TRUE; // Allow access.
  }

  return FALSE; // Default for anything that doesn't match your criteria.
}
```

The above is a contrived example, real-world will be different depending on exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Seems like there's another way to pass the $nid to the access callback instead of meny_get_object if all you need is the $nid. Add this to the menu $items:
`$items['foo']['access arguments'] = array(2),`  and then receive the nid: `function MYMODULE_access_callback(nid) {`